# Deploying JavaFX Application Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have made a javafx program which i want to deploy into a running jar file however it seems to not be working as when i double click the jar it wont open.

i tried opening it from the command line here is the error message : [Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIZ2L.png)

But the class actually exists in the application package. The unzipped version is this: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq2Kz.png)

i think its something to do with the dependencies I'm using or how they are setup in export settings or something.

i went ahead and checked the ones i am using in the build path settings but that did not change anything here are all the build path settings:

- [Order and Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R9Zs.png)
- [Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiMen.png)
- [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CizXq.png)
- [Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dWRD.png)

I have been trying at it for days please help me 
Here is the repository if you need it [Repo Link](https://github.com/AymanHamdoun/organizer)

Thank you

Comment: How did you build your jar file?

Comment: Why don't you add a build script, with maven for example

Comment: Check this https://github.com/zonski/hello-javafx-maven-example

Comment: Does the jar file contain `application/Launcher.class`, and is it a subclass of `Application`?

Comment: James_D yes it does and yes it is

Comment: Dina Bodgan eclipse export as runnable jar

Comment: Victor Gubin one of my important dependencies is not present in maven repo im using a jar called jfeonix